# Writing a block of calls to avoid any exceptions being thrown

Tags: c#, exception

I have a particularly ugly piece of test code that is calling a number of methods on a hardware device to test it's capabilities. It needs to gracefully fail in that if any of the methods throw an exception I wan't the others to still be tested. Is there a more elegant way to represent a block of calls none of which I want to generate an exception?

```
 ...
 try
 {
     ExternalDevice.Call1();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {}
 try
 {
     ExternalDevice.Call2();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {}
 try
 {
     ExternalDevice.Call3(); 
 } catch (Exception e)
 {}
 //... many more like this
 ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend doing so, but here is a way:

```
void Absorb(Action action)
{
     try { action(); } catch { };
}

// ....
Absorb(() => ExternalDevice.Call1());
Absorb(() => ExternalDevice.Call2());
Absorb(() => ExternalDevice.Call3());
```

Note that, usually, you can use method groups to achieve simpler syntax:

```
Absorb(ExternalDevice.Call1);
Absorb(ExternalDevice.Call2);
Absorb(ExternalDevice.Call3);
```

To make it even shorter,

```
void Absorb(params Action[] actions)
{
     foreach (var action in actions) try { action(); } catch { };
}

So you can

Absorb(ExternalDevice.Call1, ExternalDevice.Call2, ExternalDevice.Call3);
```

Comment: Yep - I know it's bad practice. It's an unusual situation though - the actual exception is generic so I have to get the error code from the device with another call.

Comment: Added more syntactic sugar, just fiddling (in practice this would hardly be useful)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method that makes the call and then hides the exceptions like so

```
//Use only for test code
private void CallAndIgnoreException(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch
    {
         //probably want to add some logging here
    }
}
```

Then you can just do

```
CallAndIgnoreException(() => ExternalDevice.Call1());
CallAndIgnoreException(() => ExternalDevice.Call2());
CallAndIgnoreException(() => ExternalDevice.Call3());
```

I assume you have some other way to see if the calls failed? 
A better solution would be to have each of the calls in a separate test.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list of `Action`s:

```
Action[] actions = new Action[]
{
    ExternalDevice.Call1,
    ExternalDevice.Call2,
    ExternalDevice.Call3
};

foreach (Action action in actions)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Error with this action()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a C# programmer, but is this possible to do?

```
static object InvokeMethod(Delegate method){
    try{
        method.DynamicInvoke();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {}
}

static void Test(){
    InvokeMethod(new Func<>(ExternalDevice.Call1));
}
```